# Check activation code on first app run

Tags: java, android

I created an android app that when it runs for the first time an activation page loads with these codes .

```
    Button btnInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String strInput = m.getText().toString();
            if (strInput.equals("123") || strInput.equals("456"))
                startActivity(new Intent(ActiveCode.this, MainActivity.class));
            else
            startActivity(new Intent(ActiveCode.this,ActiveCode.class));
            finish();


        }

    });

}
```

And Main activity code like this :

```
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
    Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

    if (!welcomeScreenShown) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActiveCode.class));

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
        editor.commit();// Very important to save the preference

    }


}
```

the problem is that when on first run user closes the app completely without entering code and open it again they don't need to enter code and it goes directly to main activity , so basically it's a bug of my app .
I want help to change codes in a way that activation page disappear only when user enters code.

Comment: check your default preference  
editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);  and try

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately even after correct password it stays in that page

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize preference like this,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

instead of,

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Because your preference is not binding with your activity.